# Passing data between client and Flask

Tags: python, ajax, flask

I have a Flask application where I have a form that collects some user input. That input is then passed as JSON data via an AJAX call to a function in my Python script.

This function calls an API, gets some new data and then returns a redirect URL to the AJAX call. On success, AJAX then redirects to this new template with window.location.href.

I tried 'passing' the first view function, the_search, over to the second view function to then render the appropriate template but this didn't do the trick unfortunately. I've also tried setting the data as a session variable and then accessing it in the template but this doesn't seem to work either.

**My issue**

How can I access the variable 'response' within the redirected template, results.html?

AJAX script

```
...
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/the_search',
  data: JSON.stringify(data),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data, status) {
    window.location.href = data['website'];
  },
  error: function() {
      console.log('there was an error');
  }
})
...
```

Python script

```
@app.route('/the_search', methods=("POST", 'GET'))
def the_search():
  data = json.loads(request.data)
  lat = data['latitude']
  longitude = data['longitude']

  response = unirest.get("https://zilyo.p.mashape.com/search?latitude={}&longitude={}".format(lat, longitude),
    headers={
      "X-Mashape-Key": "k6HBYxvy88mshQ6Yg1xPVuv7Vg9Np1GZj7IjsnPxploykdpaHA",
      "Accept": "application/json"})

  session['search_results'] = response.body

  return jsonify({'website': '/results'}), 200


@app.route('/results', methods=('POST', 'GET'))
def results():
  #How can I pass the_search view function to here while still having access to the response data

  print session['search_results']

  return render_template('results.html')
```